# Can AES ciphertext stealing be supported in a node.js / javascript application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aes

We have an external interface that is using the BouncyCastle java library for encryption. In particular, it uses the AES_128_CS1_HMAC_SHA256 cipher suite, and we need to exchange data over the interface with our node.js based services. I was hoping to accomplish this by using the stock crypto module in node.js but I haven't been able to find anything that supports the CS1 ciphertext stealing mode.

Can the standard node.js crypto module be configured to support the CS1 mode? I feel like I'm not familiar enough with all of the various crypto acronyms and it's staring me in the face but I just don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

After failing to find a relevant, existing node / javascript solution, I decided to go the sidecar route. BouncyCastle wrapped in a Java Spring application with a RESTful interface. Not as ideal as native to JS, but gets the job done.